# Why might Visual Studio 2017 be showing an error of 'day_point':undeclared identifier, when Howard Hinnant's date.h header is used?

Tags: c++

The problem is an error caused anytime I try to use day_point, which is one of the commands that is shown to be used with Howard Hinnant's date.h header file. The header file is saved in the correct place and has worked so far with the all the other commands. The code was basically copied from a presentation so the problem is probably not the code itself.

Ive tried re copying the date.h file to the same folder as the c++ source file. And i've tried opening a new project and running the code in it. Neither worked. The undeclared identifier is the only error other than not recognizing the dp variable

```
#include"date.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>

int main(){
day_point dp = floor<days>(system_clock::now());
cout << "dp = " << dp << endl;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure day_point is declared in the global namespace?

Comment: My bad.  I needed to rename `day_point` to `sys_days` after a minor redesign about 3 years ago.  I wish I could change that presentation retroactively.  Though the bulk of the information in there is still 100% correct.  For the code archaeologist, most of the variable names did not change in the examples and are still `dp`. :-)  `dp` is now short for "day-precision time_point". :-)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using an old example. Days are represented by the type `date::sys_days`. See the current documentation at https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html.

If you use `auto` then you don't even need to name the type.

The relevant part of the documentation is

> **Example: Today**
>
> To get today as a sys_days, use system_clock::now() and floor to convert the time_point to a sys_days:

```
auto today = floor<days>(system_clock::now());
```

Comment: oh. ok. Thanks. It was an example from the youtube video(2015). That helps a lot.

Comment: @humbleB73 Note to people born around 2000: YouTube videos as a learning tool are almost always a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: Yeah, that one renaming of `day_point` to `sys_days` pretty much destroys the entire value of the introduction of what was to become a major addition to `<chrono>` in C++20...

Answer (score 2):

The [header](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h) does not appear to declare such a type. I quoted the documentation in Alan's post.